# Coupling calls to `\directlua` and `\latelua`

Tags: luatex

Suppose I have a lua table `bucket`. Now I'd like to add a new item to `bucket`
inside `\directlua` and later extend this same item inside `\latelua`. Like this:

```
\directlua{
  bucket = {}
  function addItem(name)
    bucket[\string#bucket + 1] = { name = name }
    return \string#bucket
  end
}


\directlua{
  idx1 = addItem("foo")
}
\latelua{
  bucket[idx1]["pos"] = 111
}


\directlua{
  idx2 = addItem("bar")
}
\latelua{
  bucket[idx2]["pos"] = 222
}

\bye
```

Is it possible to rewrite this example without using `idx1` and `idx2`?

The purpose of this is to put theses paired calls of `\directlua`/`\latelua` into a user macro. (Writing just one macro, and not one macro for each new item.)

`\directlua` provides arguments `<name>` and `<16-bit-number>`. Could these arguments be used to achieve this?

Comment: the latelua is going to run at some unspecified time after some number of your directlua calls have run, you will need something equivalent to your variables to say which item to use. The use case looks very odd though, why not use latelua for all, then  your bucket access can just access the last added item and no variables are needed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I must admit it looks odd. It's probabely better to do a refactoring and put the necessary stuff into `\latelua`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like

```
\directlua{
  bucket = {}
  function addItem(name)
    bucket[\string#bucket + 1] = { name = name }
    return \string#bucket
  end
}


\directlua{
  tex.print("\string\\latelua{bucket[" ..  addItem("foo") .. "][\string\"pos\string\"] = 111}")
}

\directlua{
  tex.print("\string\\latelua{bucket[" ..  addItem("bar") .. "][\string\"pos\string\"] = 222}")
}

x

\vfill
\break

\directlua{
print("\string\n: ", bucket[1]['pos'])
print("\string\n: ", bucket[2]['pos'])
}

\bye
```

which gives terminal output

```
:       111

:       222
```

showing the buckets are set up after the page break.

Comment: Yes, this works! Using `tex.print()` here is great, in comparison to doing everything in TeX with a countless number of `\expandafter` and `\noexpand`. Thank you.